# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object test class

Tags: unit-test, webservices, httpcalloutmock

I have a class that makes a callout, it works fine, but the test class fails

```
 @isTest
global class FinacleMockResponseGenerator2 implements WebServiceMock {
    global void doInvoke(
        Object stub, 
        Object request, 
        Map<String, Object> response,
        String endpoint, 
        String soapAction, 
        String requestName,
        String responseNS, 
        String responseName, 
        String responseType) {        

            soapFinacle.FinacleServicePort respElement = 
                new soapFinacle.FinacleServicePort();       

            soapFinacle.doBalanceEnquiryResponse  response_x = new soapFinacle.doBalanceEnquiryResponse();
            response_x.ResponseCode = 'test';            
            response_x .AccountName = 'test';
            response_x.AccountNumber = '12345678';
            response_x.AccountStatus = 'test';
            response_x.AvailableBalance = 'test';
            response_x.LedgerBalance = 'test';
            response_x.ResponseDescription = 'SUCCESS';
            response_x.ResponseStatus = 'SUCCESS';    

            soapFinacle.accountBalanceDetails x = new soapFinacle.accountBalanceDetails(); 
            x.accountBalance[0].BalanceType = 'test';
            x.accountBalance[0].BalanceAmountValue = 'test';
            x.accountBalance[0].BalanceAmountCurrency  = 'test';

            response_x.AccountBalanceDetails = x;
            response.put('response_x', response_x);                      
    }
}
```

TEST CLASS

```
 @isTest
private class FetchAccountBalancesTest2 {

  @isTest static void testCallOut(){
     Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new FinacleMockResponseGenerator2());

     Account a = new Account();
     a.Name ='Rogue Lamaine';
     a.Tier__c = 'Tier 2';
     a.Ecosystem_Status__c = 'Prospect';
     a.Transregional__c = 'Yes';
     a.Country_Code__c = '207';
     insert a;

     Current_Product_Holding__c x = new Current_Product_Holding__c();
     x.Client__c = a.id;
     x.Account_Number__c = '12345678';
     insert x;

     Test.startTest();
     FetchAccountBalances.getAccountBalance(x.id);
     Test.stopTest();

  }
}
```

Comment: In what line does the error occur?

Comment: x.accountBalance[0].BalanceType = 'test'; <-----

Comment: Lines where the error is occuring.  x.accountBalance[0].BalanceType = 'test'; <--- Mock Response Class and --->FetchAccountBalances.getAccountBalance(x.id); in the test class

Comment: I don't know what the constructor of soapFinacle.accountBalanceDetails looks like, but it seems that it does not initialize accountBalance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the `accountBalance` member within the `soapFinacle.accountBalanceDetails` `x`.

It will be something like this:

```
 soapFinacle.accountBalanceDetails x = new 
 soapFinacle.accountBalanceDetails(); 

 // Init the accountBalance property before using it.
 x.accountBalance = new List<WhatEverTypeAccountBalanceIs>();
 x.accountBalance.add(new WhatEverTypeAccountBalanceIs());

 x.accountBalance[0].BalanceType = 'test';
 x.accountBalance[0].BalanceAmountValue = 'test';
 x.accountBalance[0].BalanceAmountCurrency  = 'test';
```